# How do I implement a search feature with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a [blog application](http://www.codetunnel.com) that models a database using Entity Framework. The problem with this blog is that it has become difficult to find things I'm looking for. It needs a search function, but I'm not sure how to implement this with SQL and/or LINQ to Entities.

Right now I am searching my database with this LINQ query but it seems like it should be better.

```
    public IEnumerable<BlogPost> SearchBlogPosts(string query, int page, int itemsPerPage)
    {
        var result = _dataContext.BlogPosts
            .Where(BlogPostContains(query))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.PostedDate)
            .Skip((page - 1) * itemsPerPage)
            .Take(itemsPerPage),
        return result;
    }

    private Func<BlogPost, bool> BlogPostContains(string query)
    {
        return x => x.Title.Contains(query) || x.Body.Contains(query) || x.Author.Contains(query);
    }
```

One big problem with this is that the search is case sensitive.

Question 1) Is there a better way to do searching with LINQ to Entities?

Question 2) What about with just plain SQL? How would I write a search stored procedure in SQL Server so that I can map and use that in EF instead of LINQ?

I just want a case-insensitive search that is performed in the database so as to maintain good performance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard approach for this would be a SQL fulltext search. You will have to enable fulltext on the DB, designate column(s) to be fulltext indexed and then will then be able to use SQL [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) queries using these columns.

Fulltext search queries are currently not supported by Linq to Entities - you will have to resort to standard SQL queries for this. You can use [`ExecuteStoreQuery()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) to at least map the search results to typed result.

Comment: Sounds good. I'm glad that there is a standard way to do this. I don't mind if I have to create a stored procedure since I can map those as methods in Entity Framework. I will follow your link. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The default collation of SQL Server is case-insensitive which means that a where clause like this (which is what LINQ to Entities would create out of `Contains`)...

```
where Name like '%JOHN%'
```

...should find "john Wayne". I believe that your query is not executed on the server but actually with LINQ to Objects in memory - and there the search is case sensitive. It's LINQ to Objects because you are not returning an `Expression` from your `BlogPostContains`. The signature should be:

```
private Expression<Func<BlogPost, bool>> BlogPostContains(string query)
```

If your are only returning `Func<BlogPost, bool>` you are working with the `IEnumerable` (and not the `IQueryable`) overload of the `Where` extension method which in turn causes the whole `BlogPosts` table loaded first into memory. Then the filter is applied in memory with LINQ to Objects.

Would be interesting to know if the case-sensitivity disappears if you return an `Expression`.

(Just as a note about your Case-Sensitivity problem, not a solution to your general question about the best way to implement a Search feature.)

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood. I was unaware my Func would cause it to pull into memory. You were correct. Expression did indeed fix the case sensitivity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Lucene.Net for a good search provider.

Answer (score 0):

As per your searches using LINQ, you can try something like this and it works just fine:

```
(x.Title).ToUpper().Contains(query.ToUpper())
```

Or the similar method of ToLower() should suffice as well.

For databases that truly consider an uppercase 'A' different from a lowercase 'a' as different values, which they are technically are, the above LINQ procedure will get you the results.

Hope this helps.